# Convert JSON to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, performance

here is my JSON code:

`[{"time":"18:00:00"},{"time":"10:00:00"},{"time":"16:30:00"}]`

I want to do the following:

1. Extract the times from the json code: so: 18:00:00, 10:00:00, 16:30:00
2. I want to convert the times to this: [18,0], [10,0], [16,30]
3. I want to put it in an array.

**The final result should be**:

```
var final = [ [18,0], [10,0], [16,30] ];
```

how can i do this in the most efficient and fastest (system performance) way possible?

Comment: One loop, a split, removing leading zeros, and then pushing to an array... I don't see which part of all that is giving you difficulties.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There is no such thing as JSON *code* – JSON is *always* a string

Comment: You ask for most efficient way when in reality with no attempt of your own shown it really sounds more like *"any way"*. The objective here is for you to show **your code** and people help you fix what isn't working as expected. This is not a free code writing or tutorial service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could splice the values and get only the first two elements as number.

```js
var array = [{ time: "18:00:00" }, { time: "10:00:00" }, { time:"16:30:00" }],
    result = array.map(o => o.time.split(':').slice(0, 2).map(Number));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you have [JSON](http://json.org/) sting, then you need to parse it with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) first.

```js
var json = '[{"time":"18:00:00"},{"time":"10:00:00"},{"time":"16:30:00"}]',
    array = JSON.parse(json),
    result = array.map(o => o.time.split(':').slice(0, 2).map(Number));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is correct. Though I don't think that the OP spent anytime trying to figure this out, and seems to have just used SO as a free coding service.

Comment: ok thanks but my `time` is wrapped in quotes like this `"time"`. it says array.map is not a function.

Comment: @JohnJaoill, maybe you have really a [JSON](http://json.org/) string, like `'[{"time":"18:00:00"},{"time":"10:00:00"},{"time":"16:30:00"}]'`, the you ned to parse it first with `JSON.pase`.